# How to remove Value of any key in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have an array of JSON which contains around 100 Objects and each object contains multiple values. I have multiple JSON files with same structure which needs data cleansing.

Is there a way using regex or something in notepad++ that I can type the Key name and delete the value of that key irrespective of the data and type it contains.

Sample json :

```
  {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    .
    .
    .
    test : [{
       position:1,
       key1: value1,
       key2: value2,
       .
       .
       .
       keyN: valueN
    },
    {
       position:2,
       key1: value1,
       key2: value2,
       .
       .
       .
       keyN: valueN
    },
    {
       position:3,
       key1: value1,
       key2: value2,
       .
       .
       .
       keyN: valueN
    },
     .
     .
     .
     {
   position:N,
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2,
   .
   .
   .
   keyN: valueN
}]

}
```

My requirement is is there a way I can delete all the position key value pair using regex or something.

Answer (score 1):

For example, this will delete the whole lines that contain the key `key2`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*key2:.+\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
key2:       # the key to be deleted
.+          # 1 or more any character
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the replace window (open with Ctrl + H), select regular expression.

If all key/value pairs are on a new line, search for the following (if you want to delete `key2` and its value) and replace it with an empty string:

```
\s*key2: .*
```